# JavaScript text node

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Trying to create a basic quiz in javaScript. My code below seems to only output the radio button and not the accompanying labels. Why is this? Heres the full [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssosina/vda85aub/6/). Thanks

```
while(i<length){
    var radioBtn = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    radioBtn.setAttribute('type','radio');
    radioBtn.id = i;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[0].choices[i]));
    radioBtn.appendChild(label);
    form.appendChild(radioBtn);
 i++
}
```

Comment: You should append the radio button to your label, not the other way around.  Radio buttons do not have children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to put the label inside the input. Inputs cannot have child nodes.

You want to put the input inside the label.

This is what you should aim for:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio">
    Hello
</label>
```

This is what your code is attempting to do:

```
<input type="radio">
    <label>
        Hello
    </label>
</input>
```

Change:

```
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[0].choices[i]));
radioBtn.appendChild(label);
form.appendChild(radioBtn);
```

to

```
label.appendChild(radioBtn);
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[0].choices[i]));
form.appendChild(label);
```

Comment: Thanks. Need to brush up on my HTML

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a `<label>` to the `<input>` and it should be the other way around. Here's an updated plunkr:

http://jsfiddle.net/kkyoc251/

Answer (score 0):

```
while(i<length){
    var radioBtn = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    radioBtn.setAttribute('type','radio');
    radioBtn.id = i;
    label.appendChild(radioBtn); // Append radio button to the label
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[0].choices[i])); // Add a text
    form.appendChild(label); // Append to the form

    i++;
}
```

OR alternatively append the `label` as the sibling for the radio button and use the `for` property of `label` element. By this way location of `label` relative to the radio button is not matter.

```
label.setAttribute('for', radioBtn.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

change  radioBtn.appendChild(label); to     form.appendChild(label);

```
while(i<length){
    var radioBtn = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    radioBtn.setAttribute('type','radio');
    radioBtn.id = i;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[0].choices[i]));
    form.appendChild(label);
    form.appendChild(radioBtn);
 i++
}
```